# scraping a table data and insert in a list with every 5 min schedule in production server in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scheduler

I am trying to extract data from this site of the table which has 382 rows.This is the site:
https://www.dsebd.org/latest_share_price_scroll_l.php
[image: table]

I am using beautifulsoup for scraping and i want this program to run every 5 min schedule.I am trying to insert the value in a json list with exactly 382 rows excluding the header and first column with numbering.this is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def convert_to_html5lib(URL, my_list):
    r = requests.get(URL)
    # Create a BeautifulSoup object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    soup.prettify()

    # result = soup.find_all("div")[1].get_text()
    result = soup.find('table', {'class': 'table table-bordered background-white shares-table fixedHeader'}).get_text()
    # result = result.find('tbody')
    print(result)
    for item in result.split():
        my_list.append(item)
    print(my_list)

    # return


details_list = []
convert_to_html5lib("http://www.dsebd.org/latest_share_price_scroll_l.php", details_list)
counter = 0
while counter < len(details_list):
    if counter == 0:
        company_name = details_list[counter]
        counter += 1
    last_trading_price = details_list[counter]
    counter += 1
    last_change_price_in_value = details_list[counter]
    counter += 1
schedule.every(5).minutes.do(scrape_stock)
```

But i am not getting all the value of the table.I want all  the data of 382 rows table as a list so later i can save it into database.But i am not getting any result and also scheduler not working.What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you are only pulling a single result `result = soup.find_all("td")[1].get_text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup for requirement

here are wrong in some points

1. scraping only 1 row.
2. use Schedule library in proper way. (reference :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-schedule-library/)

Here is your solution with changes :

```
import schedule
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def convert_to_html5lib(url,details_list):
    # Make a GET request to fetch the raw HTML content
    html_content = requests.get(url).text
    # Parse the html content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
    # extract table from webpage
    table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "table table-bordered background-white shares-table fixedHeader" })
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
        cols=row.find_all('td')
        # remove first element from row
        cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols[1:]]
        details_list.append(cols)
        print(cols)
        # return

details_list = []
counter = 0
url="http://www.dsebd.org/latest_share_price_scroll_l.php"
# schedule job for every 5 mins   
schedule.every(5).minutes.do(convert_to_html5lib,url,details_list)
# same as your logic
while counter < len(details_list):
    if counter == 0:
        company_name = details_list[counter]
        counter += 1
    last_trading_price = details_list[counter]
    counter += 1
    last_change_price_in_value = details_list[counter]
    counter += 1
# scheduler wait for 5 mins
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check my code first to get all the data in the table. Since the data here is always updated, I think it would be better to use selenium.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
url = "https://www.dsebd.org/latest_share_price_scroll_l.php"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="") // Insert your webdriver path please

driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'table table-bordered background-white shares-table fixedHeader'})

df = pd.read_html(str(table))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
[     Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  ...  Unnamed: 8  Unnamed: 9  Unnamed: 10
0             1   1JANATAMF         6.7  ...         137       4.022       605104
1             2  1STPRIMFMF        21.5  ...         215       5.193       243258
2             3    AAMRANET        52.4  ...        1227      65.793      1264871
3             4   AAMRATECH        31.5  ...         675      37.861      1218353
4             5    ABB1STMF         5.9  ...          57       2.517       428672
..          ...         ...         ...  ...         ...         ...          ...
377         378  WMSHIPYARD        11.2  ...         835      14.942      1374409
378         379         YPL        11.3  ...         247       4.863       434777
379         380  ZAHEENSPIN         8.8  ...         174       2.984       342971
380         381    ZAHINTEX         7.7  ...         111       1.301       174786
381         382  ZEALBANGLA       120.0  ...         102       0.640         5271

[382 rows x 11 columns]]
```